# Use of undeclared identifier for button image

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello when trying to change my already existing buttons background image i'm getting this error

```
Use of undeclared identifier 't1Btn'
```

The code i'm using for my .m file is

```
@synthesize t1Btn;

- (IBAction)t2Btn:(id)sender {
    UIImage *greenOut = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green out button.png"];
    [t1Btn setBackgroundImage:greenOut forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The code for my .h file is

```
@interface GroupView : UIViewController < ZBarReaderDelegate >
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *t1Btn;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *t1Btn;


- (IBAction)t1Btn:(id)sender;
```

Im still learning Obj-C so sorry if this a bad question but I have tried looking for an answer and I just cant seem to find anything. Im sure its just something simple I am missing

So any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: Get rid of `@synthesize`. Get rid of the explicit ivar. Then change the call to `[self.t1Btn setBackgroundImage...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the bit in brackets:

```
@interface GroupView : UIViewController < ZBarReaderDelegate >
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *t1Btn;
}
```

Because you've already defined the button as an `IBOutlet` right below it:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *t1Btn;
```

Then remove the call to synthesize:

```
@synthesize t1Btn;
```

Finally be sure to refer to `t1Btn` with self:

```
UIImage *greenOut = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green out button.png"];
[self.t1Btn setBackgroundImage:greenOut forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: You didn't mention that the `@synthesize` line should also be removed.

Comment: Didn't see the @synthesize call until just now.

Comment: I know it is sort of the old way of doing things, using synthesize and such. But it is not necessarily wrong is it?

Comment: Its redundant now and handled for you. Less code, less bugs.